# Writing rapidjson document to a file using PrettyWriter

Tags: rapidjson

I have been unable to find a direct answer to this question. After searching for some time, I've written the following code but I'm sure that there exists a simpler way of doing the same task.

```
int persistJSONChanges(rapidjson::Document& fa_cloneDoc, string jsonFilePath)
{
        FILE* lp_file = fopen(jsonFilePath.c_str(), "w");
        rapidjson::StringBuffer buffer;
        rapidjson::PrettyWriter<rapidjson::StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
        fa_cloneDoc.Accept(writer);

        string temp=buffer.GetString();
        unique_ptr<char[]>l_writeBuffer(new char[temp.size()]);
        rapidjson::FileWriteStream l_writeStream(lp_file, l_writeBuffer.get(), temp.size());
        rapidjson::PrettyWriter<rapidjson::FileWriteStream> l_writer(l_writeStream);
        bool l_returnStatus=fa_cloneDoc.Accept(l_writer);
        if(l_returnStatus==false)
        {
                cout<<endl<<"file update failed"<<endl;
                return -1;
           }
        fclose(lp_file);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misused the `FileWriteStream`. It just needs a buffer of arbitrary size.

You simply needs:

```
FILE* fp = fopen(...);
char buffer[1024];
FileWriteStream fs(fp, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
PrettyWriter<FileWriteStream> writer(fs);
document.Accept(writer);
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Is the size of the buffer really arbitrary? Can I use a really small value, regardless of the size of the document?

Comment: @VishalSharma Yes. This design is due to performance consideration. The size of buffer can be smaller than the JSON. You may check the source code of FileWriteStream and it is very simple.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the following which worked for me:

```
int persistJSONChanges(rapidjson::Document& fa_cloneDoc, string jsonFilePath)
{

                rapidjson::StringBuffer buffer;
                rapidjson::PrettyWriter<rapidjson::StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
                bool l_returnStatus=fa_cloneDoc.Accept(writer);
                if(l_returnStatus==false)
                {
                        fprintf(stdout,"\n[%s::%d] JSON File update failed\n",__FILE__,__LINE__);

                        return -1;
                }

                string temp=buffer.GetString();
                ofstream out(jsonFilePath.c_str(),std::ofstream::trunc);
                out<<temp;
                return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use

```
    rapidjson::Document
```

This is work for me:

```
    namespace rpj = rapidjson; 

    FILE* fp_r = fopen("json.json", "w" );

    char buf[BUF_SIZE];

    rpj::FileWriteStream os(fp_r, buf, sizeof (buf));

    rpj::PrettyWriter<rpj::FileWriteStream> writer(os);

    writer.StartObject();
    writer.String("hello");
    writer.String("world");
    writer.String("arr");
    writer.StartArray();
    writer.Int(33);
    writer.Int(34);
    writer.Int(36);
    writer.EndArray();
    writer.EndObject();

    fclose(fp_r);
```